# How to get records from db where column = ? OR IS NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a view where on the `created_at` column I have `dates` and there are few rows where the created_at column is empty.

```
`dates = [Date.today, nil]`
`Dashboard.where(created_at: dates)`
```

I tried this, is working fine, but is it the best way?

Answer (score 2):

It's better than writing the sql yourself. If your only looking for Dashboards with a date of today or nil, that's the best option. You could shorten it to:

```
Dashboard.where(created_at: [Date.today, nil])
```